# apache 2.4 howto block directory listing from all but localhost or from local net (ip)

Tags: apache2, configuration

I know that Indexes controls the printing of a directory listing if there is no index.html or index.php etc within a  block.

In Apache 2.4, What is the best (least messy way) to only serve directory listings if the request comes from either localhost (or local network IE 192.168.10 for example).

IN the various config files there are many  blocks and I would like to keep it clean an simple.

The prime reason for this is security - I seem to have continuous hacking attempts..

thanks